# Emacs ESS Mode - Tabbing for Comment Region

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am using the Emacs-Speaks-Statistics (ESS) mode for Emacs.  When editing R code, any comment lines (those starting with #) automatically get tabbed to the far right when I create a new line above it.  How should I change my .emacs.el file to fix this?

For example, I have:

```
# Comment
```

Now, after putting my cursor at the beginning of the line and pressing Enter, I get:

```
                                # Comment
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use '###' if you don't want the comments indented.  According to the [manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Indenting),

> By default, comments beginning with
>   ‘###’ are aligned to the beginning of
>   the line. Comments beginning with ‘##’
>   are aligned to the current level of
>   indentation for the block containing
>   the comment. Finally, comments
>   beginning with ‘#’ are aligned to a
>   column on the right (the 40th column
>   by default, but this value is
>   controlled by the variable
>   comment-column,) or just after the
>   expression on the line containing the
>   comment if it extends beyond the
>   indentation column.

Comment: I am glad I looked before asking this exact same question. I marked up this answer because I think it is really a better solution than the answer above. I have long thought this was a bug / problem with ESS mode, but after tweaking my syntax, my problems have all gone away.

Comment: This convention may seem odd if you do not use Emacs much.  However, this convention comes from lisp and emacs-lisp, where the number of semi-colons denotes the type of comment, and hence how it should be indented.

Answer (score 34):

Either

```
(setq ess-fancy-comments nil)
```

if you never want to indent single-`#` comments, or

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 
          (lambda () 
            (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline)))
```

if you want to change the behavior of Enter so it doesn't indent.

Comment: Rather I think you should use "#" for end-of-line comments, and these are nicely indented to the same column on purpose --> nice code "listing".
For the other comments, really do get in to the habit of using "##"
(much more than "###"): These indent as other "statements" within that block of code

Comment: I'm still in favour of deciding how many #s I should use. One is generally sufficient so this answer is greatly appreciated as my comment is not moved to a location I don't want it to be...

Answer (score 5):

Setting `ess-indent-with-fancy-comments` to nil will remove the weird single-`#` indentation, but it must be set either buffer-locally in a hook (as in Rob's answer), OR before ESS is loaded:

```
(setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil)
(require 'ess)
```

Other ways to make sure it is set before ESS is loaded, is to set it in `M-x configure`, or to set it in the `:init` section of `use-package`.

What's going on is that ESS defines styles at initialization in `ess-style-alist`, and then applies the default style in every buffer. So to make sure these styles respect `ess-indent-with-fancy-comment`, you must make sure to set it before the styles are defined.

Comment: After my upgrading to ESS 18.10.3, the hooking method does not work for me anymore. `setq` before `require ess` works.

Answer (score 3):

Jouni's answer didn't work for me. But I found an approach here that does:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2016-May/010970.html

```
   (defun my-ess-settings ()
     (setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil))
   (add-hook 'ess-mode-hook #'my-ess-settings)
```

Comment: Yes I had to do this too for it to work, otherwise it would get overriden locally.