# Disable ESS fancy comments with R

Tags: r, emacs, ess

In Emacs using ESS for editing R files, want to stop this from happening when I hit enter:

[image: auto indentation]

I understand convention is to use ### for left-aligned comments, ## for block-aligned comments, and # for these right-adjusted comments, [per here](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Indenting), but I'm looking to disable the latter.

[I understand from other answers, it is common to encourage simply not using single comments `#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622048/left-justified-comments-for-ess), but how would I achieve this anyway?

This is in my init.el:

```
(setq ess-smart-S-assign-key nil)
;; (ess-toggle-S-assign nil)
(setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil)
(setq ess-fancy-comments nil)

(require 'ess)
(show-paren-mode 1)
;; (autoload 'R-mode "ess-site.el" "" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.R\\'" . R-mode))
;; (ess-toggle-underscore nil)

(defun my-ess-settings ()
  (setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil))
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook #'my-ess-settings)

(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline)))
```

which I have seen recommended as a way of disabling this, but still I see the behavior above in my gif.

Comment: Perhaps helpful/relevant: [Emacs ESS Mode - Tabbing for Comment Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780796/emacs-ess-mode-tabbing-for-comment-region)

Comment: Did you do add the `setq` commands *before* `(require 'ess)`?

Comment: I have run with both, same effect.

Comment: this isnt reproducible, run a bare  emacs with `emacs -Q` open an R file, and this doesn't happen.  It appears you have enabled some sort of electric indent option

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Indenting):

> Finally, comments beginning with ‘#’ are aligned to a column on the right (the 40th column by default, but this value is controlled by the variable comment-column,) or just after the expression on the line containing the comment if it extends beyond the indentation column. **You turn off the default behavior by adding the line `(setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil)` to your `.emacs` file.**

I suggest you work in something like this into your emacs config:

```lisp
(setq ess-indent-with-fancy-comments nil)
```

I set this in my spacemacs config and when I started emacs again the problem went away.

I am running this with Emacs 26.3, ESS 20200312, and very recent spacemacs.

Comment: You can see in the question that this is already included in my emacs config.

Comment: @Mittenchops What versions of things are you running?